# Convert Array Int8 to base64?

Tags: swift

I am using `TripleDES` with `IDZSwiftCommonCrypto` library.

When encrypting a text it `TripleDES` to return an array of bytes of type UInt8.

How to convert this array **cipherText** to  base64 y vice versa to transport in the service. When I try to convert **cipherText** to string using the String class return **nil**.

```
import UIKit
import IDZSwiftCommonCrypto
let  s = "0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI8"
var md5s2 : Digest = Digest(algorithm:.md5)
md5s2.update(s)
let digests2 = md5s2.final()
let algorithm = Cryptor.Algorithm.tripleDES
var iv = try! Random.generateBytes(byteCount: algorithm.blockSize())
var key = arrayFrom(hexString: hexString(fromArray: digests2))
var plainText = "test"
var cryptor = Cryptor(operation:.encrypt, algorithm:algorithm, options:.PKCS7Padding, key:key, iv:iv)
var cipherText = cryptor.update(plainText)?.final()

var decryptedString2 = String(bytes: cipherText!, encoding: .utf8) // Return nil

cryptor = Cryptor(operation:.decrypt, algorithm:algorithm, options:.PKCS7Padding, key:key, iv:iv)
var decryptedPlainText = cryptor.update(cipherText!)?.final()

var decryptedString = String(bytes: decryptedPlainText!, encoding: .utf8) // Return 'test'
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `[Int8]`? It looks like `[UInt8]` which is interchangeable with `Data`. And `Data`can be converted to `base64`.

Comment: My error, it is of type UInt8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
let ints : [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4]
let data = Data(ints)
let base64String = data.base64EncodedString() // As a String
```

I you prefer you can have it directly in `Data`:

```
let base64Data = data.base64EncodedData() // As Data
```